# Proper name for hypergrid or subdivided hypercube?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a name for a graph very similar to a hypercube, but generalized from $2^d$ vertices to $k^d$? Alternatively, similar to a 2-dimensional grid, but generalized to higher dimensions?

In 2 dimensions, it would be a square grid with a side length of $k$. In 3 or more dimensions the graph would look like a subdivided hypercube, with internal vertices each having $2d$ neighbors.

Vertices can be given coordinates with base $k$ and length $d$, with adjacent vertices differing only by one in a single dimension.

Is there a proper name for this structure? I haven't found any discussion of it with the terms used above.

Comment: In some lecture notes from Imre Leader (https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~par31/notes/extcomb.pdf from the 9th page) he refers to these graphs as "the grid" and denotes them by $[k]^n$.

Comment: Mathematica also just calls this a "grid graph" and permits the length of each side to be arbitrary. (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridGraph.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (incomplete) list of names that people use for the object (with examples):

- "generalized grid graph" ([mathematica](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html))
- "hypergrid graph" ([matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922-matlabbgl/content/matlab_bgl/grid_graph.m))
- "multi-dimensional grid graph" ([BHS](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4151))

Perhaps "hypercubical grid graph" would also not be a bad choice.

The notation $[k]^n$ suggested by Imre Leader through Daniel Soltész makes perfect sense as the $k$-fold product of the path graph $[k]$.

Comment: Also because sometimes the cube is denoted by $\{0,1\}^n$ and most of the time the set $\{0,1,\cdots , k\}$ is denoted by $[k]$. (Whether or not we include the element $0$ is up to the author.)

Comment: This may not be what you look for, but in 3D a subdivision of a cube into identical cubes would resemble a special kind of crystal; so maybe calling graphs that are generated by subdividing hyperspace into identical, iso-oriented cells could be called hyper crystal graphs.